# Arduino communication through 'Serial Monitor'

Tags: arduino

I've taken my Arduino out of the box about an hour ago and I'm trying to get some bits of code working.

The code below is supposed to wait for an input from the Serial Monitor and set the [LED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) connected at terminal 9 to the input value.

The Arduino reads the value the first time, but it always sets the LED to full brightness and never prints the "input invalid". The Arduino also doesn't read any value after the first one. What is the reason?

```cpp
int A;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("input value");
}


void loop()
{
  A = 0;                      /* Reset A */
  if (Serial.available() > 0) /* Wait for input */
  {
    A = Serial.read();        /* Read input */
    if(A >= 0 && A <= 255)    /* Check for valid input */
    {
      analogWrite(9, A);      /* Set value of an LED */
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("input invalid");
    }
  }

  delay(100);                 /* Wait 0.1 second */
}
```

Comment: I think you should use `Serial.parseInt()` instead of reading one character by `read()`. And if you move fast with the LED and you can see flickering (trail), then it is not on its "full brightness".

Answer (score 0):

According to the rest of code the `Serial.parseInt()` should be used instead of reading one character by `Serial.read()`.